# Extract data from JSON file in to a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dataset on this link (Pretty Print Copy):

```
[
  [
    [
      "ICE   78",
      1410011548,
      513933251,
      "84/460303/18/19/80",
      "17",
      1,
      "55",
      "Hamburg-Altona",
      [
        [
          206,
          -144,
          -476,
          "11",
          "36",
          null,
          null
        ],
        [
          -90,
          72,
          2477,
          "11",
          "37",
          null,
          null
        ],
        [
          -279,
          189,
          4192,
          "11",
          "36",
          null,
          null
        ],
        [
          -2922,
          1654,
          26958,
          "12",
          "37",
          null,
          null
        ],
        [
          -3129,
          1762,
          28673,
          "12",
          "35",
          null,
          null
        ],
        [
          -3380,
          1870,
          30674,
          "13",
          "35",
          null,
          null
        ],
        [
          -3596,
          1951,
          32292,
          "13",
          "37",
          null,
          null
        ],
        [
          -4045,
          2095,
          35531,
          "",
          "0",
          null,
          null
        ]
      ],
      "Hamburg Dammtor",
      "8002548",
      "Hamburg-Altona",
      "8002553",
      "28.11.17",
      "2",
      null,
      "13:50",
      "13:43",
      null,
      "54",
      "0",
      null,
      null
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

*Basic Information about the data: The dataset is a realtime information about a transport company and their trains.*

The data copied in this way from a pretty print view from Firefox. **I want to parse this page and will then extract the data to a useful structure. Like a dictionary.**

I have tried some approaches, unfortunately without success, I am happy about all ideas.

I have tried following approach:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:

    data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Comment: don't link to external sites. just create a [mcve]

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, the post has been edited

Comment: What is the error message or other problem you encounter with your current approach?

Comment: @dllahr The data is simply written as raw text in the files. I miss the approach to get the data into a dictionary.

Comment: @madik_atma How should your dictionary look like? Also the data set in your question is not json it's just a bunch of nested lists.

Comment: @madik_atma You've written code above, you said you tried it.  What happens when you try it?